# Generics - get Class<T[]> from Class<T>

Tags: java, generics

```
public class GenericClass<T> {

    private final Class<T> clazz;

    public GenericClass(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

}

public Test extends GenericClass<Person.class> {

    public Test() {
        super(Person.class);
    }

}
```

in the Generic class, I will be passing clazz (in this case Person.class) as an argument in one of the methods, but now I want to pass clazz[] (in this case Person[].class) in another method inside Generic class. How do I do that? how can I get clazz[] from clazz i.e., Person[].class from Person.class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answer I've ever been able to find is

```
 Array.newInstance(myClass, 0).getClass()
```

Comment: I am calling rest template in the Generic class and want to pass Class type in the methods. for example

restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, this.clazz, params);

and 

restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, this.clazz[], params);

is there any way to pass the generic array of class in the method (in this case Person[].class)

I couldn't able to figure out how Array.newInstance(myClass, 0).getClass() works

Comment: @Shiva this answer gets you `Person[].class` if you just put it in.

Comment: got it. It works now I had to cast it 
Class<T[]> arrayClass = (Class<T[]>) Array.newInstance(this.clazz, 0).getClass(); 
Thanks @Louis